# Same URL serves different content - why?

Tags: javascript, url, cookies, browser, content-type

If you are logged in, this URL: https://download.ama-assn.org/resources/doc/usan/x-pub/usan-february-2014-newsletter.pdf returns html page:

```
<div id="dlblock">
    <a href="http://www.ama-assn.org">
        <img src="https://www.ama-assn.org/resources/images/header/ama-logo.png" border="0">
    </a><br><br>
    You are about to download<br>
    <strong>
         <a id="file-link" href="/resources/doc/usan/x-pub/usan-february-2014-newsletter.pdf" target="_blank">usan-february-2014-newsletter.pdf</a>
    </strong>
    If you are not automatically redirected, please 
    <a href="/resources/doc/usan/x-pub/usan-february-2014-newsletter.pdf" target="_blank">click here</a> 
    to begin your download.   <br><br>
    <small>Copyright 1995-2014 
        <a href="http://www.ama-assn.org">American Medical Association</a> All rights reserved.
    </small>
```

If you click on the link on this page (and the url is the the same page just opened in new window) you will get pdf.

I don't understand how can server decide when to serve html and when pdf - how is this implemented?

Comment: How do you think does a server decide whether you're logged in or not?

Comment: Yeah it's really a mystery.

Comment: Which *"link"* are you referring to? the one that points at a .pdf?

Comment: @D.Kasipovic Please don't laugh - I can't find any difference in cookies. Also, lets assume I have this page opened in two tabs - html on one tab, pdf on the second one. If that were cookies after I access second tab, with pdf, refreshing first one should give me pdf as well. And this doesn't work that way.

Comment: @KevinB - in whole wuestion there is only one URL: https://download.ama-assn.org/resources/doc/usan/x-pub/usan-february-2014-newsletter.pdf

Comment: Is there a session cookie?

Comment: @Bergi - please read my comment above.

Comment: And if you remove id="file-link" (replace file-link with blabla in chrome console)?

Comment: @D.Kasipovic - I need to check that - but how would that alter the behaviour? Anyway, if I switch js completely, I will get empty response. I was trying to find some js code setting any cookie but I could find any apart from google analytics, which I've checked and is irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe it's not cookie, maybe there is onClick trigger on the link?

Comment: I've installed 'visual event' chrome extension, doesn't report any events in js, but I've also check js code, no 'click' bindings at all...

Comment: Well, there are only two possibilities: Either the requests are different, or the server has some state. As you say JS affects it, chances are high for the first option. Please post the requests (headers & body) as you find them in the chrome devtool's network tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server may read the `http referer` request header, and if it matched the URL of the page, serve the PDF version instead.

Comment: Nope, I've checked that.

Comment: Where did you check that? In the server script, or in the HTTP request?

Comment: I was just sending requests with different values of this header or completely without it, no effect at all.

Comment: Completely compare the HTTP requests when clicking on the link, to browsing directly. Are the URLs different? Are there any other different headers at all?

Comment: If I saw any difference in headers, cookies or GET params I wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Except there is definitely at least one difference - http-referer

Comment: I'm a little embarrassed to admit it - but I created an account just to test it. I'm right, it's the referer header that causes the server to load the pdf, and not the html. Probably just checks that the URL is the same as the referred url, et voila!